# Drawing on canvas with separate thread Android

Tags: android, multithreading, canvas

Hi I am trying to use SurfaceView and Threads in order to draw faster on Canvas. So far I have accomplished to draw on canvas by simply extending View class and draw in onDraw method. Also, I have ability to redraw the canvas if user make input over keyboard(by passing keycode from an activity to the custom view).

The problem is that I am stuck with multithreading, I have substituted the View class with the SurfaceView and implemented Runnable(followed [this](http://android-coding.blogspot.rs/2011/05/basic-implementation-of-surfaceview.html) tutorial). But I cannot pass keycode if key input has occurred. Also, if I call invalidate() method on custom view, nothing happens. The only difference from tutorial code and mine is that I have added to end of while loop this line:

```
retry = false;
```

In order to stop executing thread after drawings. And added after every click in activity this line so I can redraw everything again.

```
view.resume();
```

Problems: 
 -view doesn't invalidate on key events and doesn't draw new images(not sure why)

- if i stop thread by calling thread.join(); method, will other objects inside CustomView remain in heap memory or they will be destroy?
- how to make this app to execute automatically at start and afterwards to execute only on click?
- why invalidate method doesn't clear the canvas if I explicitly call before view.resume()?

p.s. I I need to post code samples, please let me know and I will attach git repo with test app.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In android you have the Handler class that you can implement to send messages, you create it inside the Thread you want to receive and implement handleMessage, on other Threads you use sendMessage.

Another thing, for boolean flags and multi-threading, you should use the keyword volatile to some VM optimizations.

```
volatile boolean retry = false;
```

Comment: I added the volatile keyword, but nothing has changed. thanks